# What is the difference between a cast to BOOL and sending the message boolValue?

Tags: objective-c, casting

What is the difference between these two methods that I believe do the same thing (cast to a `BOOL`):

```
BOOL boolOne = (BOOL) [dictionary objectForKey:@"boolValue"];
BOOL boolTwo = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"boolValue"] boolValue];
```

When should either be used over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are quite different.

The first gets an object pointer from the dictionary, then interprets the *pointer* as  a `BOOL`. This means that any non-`nil` pointer will be interpreted as `YES`, and `nil` as `NO`. In the concrete example, as dictionaries cannot contain `nil` pointers, you will only ever get `YES` from this line of code.

The second one takes the same object from the dictionary, then sends the message `boolValue`to that object. Presumably, and if the object recognizes the message, that will result in a `BOOL` version of the object.

As a concrete example, if the dictionary contains an `NSNumber` associated with the key `@"boolValue"`, the `NSNumber` will receive the message `boolValue`, and if it is non-zero return `YES`, otherwise `NO`.

So to answer your question, you should use the second form. Casting a pointer to a `BOOL` rarely makes any sense.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not the same. The difference is that 2nd one is correct one, 1st one is not.

In your 1st line you simply cast pointer to BOOL which is roughly equivalent to checking if pointer is nil or not and has nothing to do with the value actually stored in the object.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[dictionary objectForKey:@"boolValue"] boolValue];
```

is not a cast, but calls a method on NSNumber, that returns a bool. Inside a cast might be involved — but the implementation details aren't public.